# Create a HUD window programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

I need to create a HUD-like window programmatically when the user press on my main view. Here's the code I use, but I only get a standard window.

```
videoWindow= [[NSPanel alloc]
      initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(200.0, 200.0, 300, 200) 
      styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask 
      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[videoWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Perhaps I'm not using the right flags, but I didn't find in the documentation or on Google. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `NSPanel` with the `NSHUDWindowMask` style mask.